# Timer Javascript

Tags: javascript

This doesn't work in IE. Forever - 00:00:00
Works in Chrome, Firefox.
Why?
How can I fix it?

```
function timer()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var enddate = new Date("07,12,2012,23:00:00");
    var totalRemains = (enddate.getTime()-now.getTime());
    if (totalRemains>1)
    {
        var RemainsSec=(parseInt(totalRemains/1000));
        var RemainsFullDays=(parseInt(RemainsSec/(24*60*60)));
        var secInLastDay=RemainsSec-RemainsFullDays*24*3600;
        var RemainsFullHours=(parseInt(secInLastDay/3600));
        if (RemainsFullHours<10){RemainsFullHours="0"+RemainsFullHours};
        var secInLastHour=secInLastDay-RemainsFullHours*3600;
        var RemainsMinutes=(parseInt(secInLastHour/60));
        if (RemainsMinutes<10){RemainsMinutes="0"+RemainsMinutes};
        var lastSec=secInLastHour-RemainsMinutes*60;
        if (lastSec<10){lastSec="0"+lastSec};
        var mcend = Date.parse("Jan 1, 2009, 00:00:00");
        var mcnow = now.getTime();
        var mc = ((mcend-mcnow)/10).toFixed(0).substr(8);
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: '+ RemainsFullHours+":"+RemainsMinutes+":"+lastSec+'</p>';
        setTimeout("timer()",10);
    } 
    else {document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = '<p class="timeline">TIME LEFT: 00:00:00</p>';}
}

<body onload="timer();">
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var enddate = new Date("07,12,2012,23:00:00");
```

This is not a date format. Firefox is heroically making sense out of it, don't expect Internet Explorer to help you out the same, IE is ruthless, he walks alone.

The `Date` object constructor takes several parameters:

> new Date()
> new Date(milliseconds)
> new Date(dateString)
> new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])

When using the `dateString` option, your date string must conform to [the RFC 2822 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14); it works if you use a supported format:

```
var enddate = new Date("July 12, 2012 23:00:00");
```

AND, never, never, never pass a string to `setTimeout`, pass it a function reference instead:

```
setTimeout(timer,10);
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bVCMe/

**Documentation**

- `window.setTimeout` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout
- `Date` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/
- RFC 2822 string date format specification - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14